# Agenda telefonica

Tags: python

Estou desenvolvendo um programa em python que deve receber nome e telefone de um contato e armazenar em uma agenda em ordem alfabetica. Até aqui está tudo bem.
O problema aparece quando preciso implementar uma opção de busca (linha 19), onde o usuario informa o nome do contato que ele procura e o programa retorna o nome e numero pedido.

Abaixo esta o programa, alguem pode me ajudar a implementar essa função?

#### Agenda telefonica

```
agenda=[]
n_contato=int(input("Quantos contatos voce deseja salvar? "))
itens=1
def Agenda_Telefonica
    for i in range(n_contato):
        contato=[]
        for j in range(itens):
            nombre=input("Cual es el nombre del contato, mi amigx? ")
            telefono=int(input("Cual es el telefono? "))
            contato.append(nombre)
            contato.append(telefono)
        agenda.append(contato)
        return agenda
agenda.sort()   ### colocado em ordem alfabetica ###
print("Vossa agenda telefonica tienes ",len(agenda),"contatos salvos, sendo ellos",agenda)

index=agenda.index.contato.index(input("Estas a procurar el contato de quem? "))
print("El contatito que tu procuras es: ",agenda(index))
```

Comment: Reformate melhor sua pergunta e seu código, utilize a sintaxe do markdown para postar trechos de código na sua pergunta, desta forma, as pessoas ficarão mais aptas a ajudar você.

Answer (score 0):

A agenda inteira poderia ser um dicionário cuja chave é o nome da pessoa e o valor é o número de telefone (ou uma lista de telefones, se preferir). Não faz sentido implementar a agenda como uma lista que tem outra lista dentro.

Uma vez que a agenda agora é um dicionário, você pode salvar um contato dessa forma:

`agenda[“fulanito”] = “666-2424”`

E você pode recuperar o telefone dessa forma:

```
print(agenda [“fulanito”])
```

A lista de todos os nomes da agenda você teria com o método keys, dessa forma:

```
agenda.keys()
```

Dessa forma, o usuário digita o nome do contato e você retorna o item da agenda facilmente.